# Headings in an ol, indent left or negative text-indent

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to have the heading to the left of the list item.
I don't want to nest an ordered list inside of an unordered because I need the list items to be continuous between headings.

This is what I have been using, but I don't like that the heading is indented right, despite not being included in the list item.

Tried using "text-indent:-2em" on the heading but that didn't work. 
I even tried creating a separate div and putting the negative text indent there, but that didn't work either.

```html
<ol reversed>
    <h3>year</h3>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <h3>year</h3>
    <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Tried a few websites:
https://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479461

Comment: Run your page through the W3C validator, correct the errors, and then come back here if there are still problems.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you are on the right path with the -2em to reverse the indent, but it needs to be placed on "margin-left" instead of "text-indent", and either create a class to call it each time you want to use it:

in CSS:

```
.unindent{
    margin-left: -2em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ol reversed>
    <h3 class="unindent">year</h3>
    <li >item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <h3 class="unindent">year</h3>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ol>
```

or individually add it to the lines you want "un-indented":

```
    <ol reversed>
        <h3 style="margin-left: -2em" >year</h3>
        <li >item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <h3 style="margin-left: -2em" >year</h3>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ol>
```

There may be other ways, but that's the simplest way I could think of. Good luck!